# How to insert a record into table that has a user id as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

My database structure is like so:

Table 1: customers

```
| userid | username | password      |   email           | 
|  1     | bob      | mypassword123 | bob@gmail.com     |
```

Please note that 'userid' is a primary key in this table

Table 2: accountbalance

```
| userid   | balance |
|    1     |   100   |
```

Please note that 'userid' in accountbalance table is a foreign key to the 'userid' field in customers table.

When a new account is created, I not only want a new row in customers to be created, but I want a corresponding row in accountbalance to be created to give a started value of 100 ($100) but the problem is how do I know what the userid is?

I thought about running a query to look for the id using the username and then doing an INSERT INTO statement in the accountbalance. Would that work? Can I get a general outline?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what db you use. Mysql has `LAST_INSERT_INSERT_ID()` function which you can call after your insert (just call `SELECT LAST_INSERT_INSERT_ID()`) and you'll get the id of last inserted row (in case your id is defined as AUTO_INCREMENT). If you use postgres it allows you to perform insert returning id. Something like `INSERT INTO customerts(...) VALUES(...) RETURNING userid`.

But as you mentioned if your `username` is unique I would use select using this attribute after insert, because it is db independent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `trigger` of mysql

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER temp AFTER INSERT ON customers
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO accountbalance SET userid = NEW.userid;
  END;
|  
delimiter ;
```

ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

set default value of `balance` field in `accountbalance` table to `100` while creating table or edit later.